# How to revert php artisan voyager:controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I put in "config/voyager.php"

```
 'controllers' => [
     'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth',
 ],
```

Then run: "php artisan voyager:controllers" Controllers were created in my Auth folder (I didn't really know why I did that). Now my page no longer has css, js or images :/.

Comment: If source control, just revert. If not, can't you just copy the controllers from the Auth directory into the Controllers directory?

Comment: Did you try `php artisan config:clear`, then run `php artisan voyager:controllers`?

Comment: I can't execute `php artisan voyager:controllers` again, the Voyager controllers files are re-created in my App\Http\Controllers\Auth, if i replace the namespace at voyager.php and re-run php artisan voyager:controllers it says `The controllers namespace must start with your application namespace: App</error>`